# C# language: How to freeze listview control in windows form?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, listview, freeze

i need to freeze certain columns in listview so when the user scrolls horizontally the frozen columns will not be affected (like in excel) but there is no frozen(bool) property like that in datagrid. Can this be done in listview control? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ListView has no support for this, nor can it easily be added.  Consider using DataGridView instead.  Its columns have a [Frozen property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e9w2e1.aspx).