# Listview first column fixed and independent from other columns c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have 6 columns in my listview. `Column 0` shows number of a row. Other columns are being loaded with some data from text files.

Is it possible to make a fixed first column that is independent from other columns and not affected by sorting in listview?

[image: first column]

If this is possible can someone give a tip on how to accomplish that ?

Comment: Don't use a ListView.  Switch to a [DataGridView and Freeze the Column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e9w2e1.aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833616/c-sharp-language-how-to-freeze-listview-control-in-windows-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking, ListView doesn't support this function. You can't do this.

I suggest use DataGridView and use its column [Frozen property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e9w2e1.aspx).

Comment: You guys are all right , it is better to use datagrid.